# Parameterizing to dynamically generate the extract file from Oracle table using Shell Script

Tags: shell, dynamic

I have a requirement where I need to parameterize to generate one extract file from multiple Oracle tables through the UNIX shell script. 
    Here is the script which I have written to generate one tab delimited file which will fetch all the data from EMPLOYEE table.
    I need to parameterize the TABLE_NAME,OWNER_NAME,USERNAME,PASSWORD and HOST to generate from 12 more tables.
    So, I would like to have only one SQL to dyngenerate the extract for 12 tables by passing these parameters values when executing the scripts.
    Could you please give me show me how we can modify the below script and how to pass the parameter during the script execution.

Second Requirement is to generate the file incrementally based on a column for example, ETL_UPDATE_TS. can you please show me this also.

Sample Scripts

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
TD=/mz/mz01/TgtFiles
MD=/mz/mz01/Scripts
#CAQH_Server=sftp.org
#UN=user
#PWD=password
#RD=Incoming
#RD=/home/

cd $TD

FILE="EMPLOYEE.TXT"

sqlplus -s scott/tiger@db  <<EOF

SET PAGES 999
SET COLSEP "    "
SET LINES 999
SET FEEDBACK OFF

SPOOL $FILE

SELECT * FROM EMP;

SPOOL OFF
EXIT
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

Handling your parameters in a similar way you did for $FILE variable and passing them as options to the script

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh
TD=/mz/mz01/TgtFiles
MD=/mz/mz01/Scripts

cd $TD
FILE="undefined"
TABLE="undefined"
while getopts :f:t: opt
do
        case $opt in
                f)      FILE=${OPTARG} ;;
                t)      TABLE=${OPTARG} ;;
                *)      echo "invalid flag" ;;
        esac
done

if [ "$TABLE" == "undefined" ]; then
    echo "ERROR. TABLE is undefined, use -f option."
    exit 1
fi
# More required variables checks here

# create more options to parameterize connection
sqlplus -s scott/tiger@db  <<EOF

SET PAGES 999
SET COLSEP "    "
SET LINES 999
SET FEEDBACK OFF

SPOOL $FILE

SELECT * FROM $TABLE;

SPOOL OFF
EXIT
EOF
```

An execute it as

```
my_script.sh -f "EMPLOYEE.TXT" -t "EMP"
```